# Ruby / Rails Instance Variables Not In Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've recently forayed into Ruby (on Rails), and now I'm stuck.

I've created a class called Habit in `habit.rb`, shown below.

```
require 'date'

class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :created_at, :start
  attr_accessor :name, :record

  belongs_to :user

  after_initialize do
    @name = name
    @record = []
    @start = Date.today.yday()
    @created_at = Time.now()
  end
end
```

Steps to reproduce issue (in `rails console --sandbox`):

1. `star_monkey = Habit.create(name: "draw star")`
2. `star_monkey`

This returns `#<Habit id: 1, name: nil, days: nil, start: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: "2013-10-14 21:32:35">`.

However, when I explicitly request an instance variable, like `@name`, `@record`, or `@start`, the proper values are returned.

```
star_monkey.name # returns "draw star"
star_monkey.record # returns []
star_monkey.start # returns 287
```

My question is: How is it that `star_monkey.#{variable}` is the correct value, but the record doesn't 'save' the proper value? And secondly, how would I remedy this?

Comment: You're conflating the term _instance variable_ with _object attribute_. `name`, `record`, and `start` are object attributes – they _can_ be instance variables, but are not typically termed in this fashion.

Comment: @zeantsoi, the only attribute that gets its value from `create` is `name`, whilst the others are intended to be instantiated whenever a new instance is created. How would you suggest I go about fixing this?

Comment: Instance variables (with @) aren't persisted to the database, they are not what links instance data to the db. Also, created_at is automatically initialized by Rails (and it's also not an instance variable with an `@`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason or another, settings attributes using the below worked.

`self[:attribute] = "value"`

Answer (score 0):

In the console you are using the `create` method which automatically saves the new object with the values provided to it. If you use `new`, then it will not save the object. If you want to check, try to see the id of the object while using `create` and `new` method. You will see the difference. When you use `create` it will automatically get saved with id in it but when you use `new` it will not save unless you use `object.save`.
Thanks

Comment: After `new` then `save`, the _attributes_ still don't apply.